# I want to run d3 from a Cakefile

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js, jsdom

I'd like to execute some d3 code from the command line. Initially I just tried something like:

```
task 'data', 'Build some data with d3', ->
      d3 = require('lib/d3.v2')
      console.log "d3 version = "+ d3.version
```

But this didn't work. I got errors like this:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
ReferenceError: CSSStyleDeclaration is not defined
    at /Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/app/lib/d3.min.js:1:21272
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/app/lib/d3.min.js:2:25395)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.action (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/Cakefile:22:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:39:26
```

So...I figured this exception was telling me that I need to execute d3 inside of a browser. I tried this in a couple different ways. Basically though, I thought if I just fired up phantomjs I'd probably be able to do what I wanted to do. Here was my Cakefile:

```
task 'data2', 'Build some data with d3', ->
  hem = spawn 'hem', ['server']
  phantom = require('phantom')
  phantom.create (ph) ->
    ph.createPage (page) ->
      page.open 'http://localhost:9294/sandbox.html', (status) ->
        page.evaluate (-> window), (window) ->
          require = window.require
          require('lib/d3.v2')
          console.log("d3 version = "+ d3.version)
          ph.exit()
          hem.kill()
```

When I go this route though, I always end up getting exceptions like this:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/Cakefile:52:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:274:16)
    at apply (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:143:17)
    at EventEmitter.handle (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:120:13)
    at /Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:81:20
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:62:13)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:46:19)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/mydir/Documents/classes/middleclass/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:46:39)
```

What am I doin wrong??

---

Thanks to mbostock I got the following working:

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "d3": "~2.8.0",
        "jsdom": "~0.2.13"
    }
}
```

My Cakefile:

```
task 'd3', 'Do something with d3', ->
  jsdom = require('jsdom')
  jsdom.env({
    html: 'public/sandbox.html'
    done: (errors,window) ->
      require('d3/index.js')
      console.log("d3 version = "+ d3.version)
  })
```

Comment: It looks like you solved your issue.
I personally got the same error, and fixed it with `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See D3's [package.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/package.json). More specifically, the file you want to require when running inside Node or similar environments is [index.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/index.js) rather than d3.v2.js; this file contains some special patches that make D3 compatible with the `require` operator.

To try it out for yourself, `cd` to the d3 repository, run `node` to create an interactive shell, and then say

```
var d3 = require("./");
```

Or, if you're in your own project folder, if you've installed D3 into node_modules/d3 via npm (`npm install d3`), you can say:

```
var d3 = require("d3");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my slightly old question - I'll try it out today. And from the d3 author no less!

Comment: Just thought I'd follow up to ask...since the author is on this thread...I tried 'npm install d3', and whilst var d3 = require('d3'); in node console gives me 'undefined' but I can do d3.version and get a number, putting it in app.js gives me: TypeError: Cannot read property 'BSON' of undefined...am I missing something?

Comment: @pland See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948350 `var d3 = require("d3");` prints "undefined" in the console because that expression evaluates to undefined; confusingly, that does not mean that the `d3` variable is undefined! The fact that you can print `d3.version` demonstrates that the package is loaded correctly.