# conflict between d3 and mongo in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, d3.js

When requiring d3.js before a module that requires mongo (connect-mongo) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'BSON' of undefined
    at .../node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/index.js:48:44
```

If I require d3.js after the mongo module it works fine...

I'm not the first to run into this issue, but I can't figure out whats conflicting
[How to use D3 in Node.js properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948350/how-to-use-d3-in-node-js-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the version of BSON you're using checks for the existence of a `window` global to see whether or not it's running in Node.JS. This is a bad idea, e.g. D3.js creates such a global via JSDOM, thus invalidating the check.

However, it looks like this issue has been fixed in a [recent commit](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/commit/80649f1d2e078e2693c9ceceb3415ec6569e33b8), i.e. in BSON v0.1.5.

At the time of writing, the version of mongodb on npmjs.org is [v1.1.11](https://npmjs.org/package/mongodb), but the BSON dependency has been updated in v1.2.0, which appears to be on the verge of being released (see GitHub).