# D3.js visualization with node.js

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I'm just starting to learn node.js and I'd like to learn how to use node to create a D3.js visual. Can anyone explain how I can go about doing this? Ideally, I'm looking for an example that is as simple as possible that I can read through the code and understand how to do this. I've looked at some length, but I haven't found any reproducible examples.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948350/how-to-use-d3-in-node-js-properly) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Node.js doesn't has any graphic interface or DOM.

You could use [a headless browser](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) in node but you would still require a real browser to render the results.

*Edit after comment:*

If what you want is a node app to serve data, try the [express framework](http://expressjs.com/api.html).

**Simple express server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/circle', function(req, res){
  // CSP headers
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  // response
  res.send({ x: 12, y: 34, r: 5 });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Use an Ajax request to get the values. Probably you want to set the [CSP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) in the response to allow cross domain requests.

**Client using jQuery:**

```
$.get('http://yourserver.com:3000/circle', function(data) {
  alert(data);
  // set here your svg properties
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm simply looking for an example that shows how to use node to push data into a D3 viz.

Comment: So you just want a node app to serve data?

Comment: This is great! One more thing I want to understand. If I want to make a svg circle with d3 and pass the x, y, and radius data to the browser to generate the circle, how can I do this? `<svg width="50" height="50">
2  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
</svg>`

Comment: Ok, I've updated the response. But I feel that your question has nothing to do with node or D3. You first need basic HTTP and javascript knowledge.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Yes, I don't usually do this type of thing, so my knowledge is lacking. I've got the server running with `node myapp.js` and I see the data at `/circle`. What is the jQuery bit. Is this a separate file? I don't see any alerts. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library: http://jquery.com/

Comment: What file does the `Client using jQuery` go into?

Comment: Inside an html document, between <script> tags. Read jQuery documentation.