# Web service with D3.js and Express.js, and several requests simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js

I have tried to find an answer to my problem but I have had no luck. I apologize in case this has already been answered.

I am trying to write a web service with Express.js. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/getgraph', function(req, res) {
    var d3 = require('d3'); 

    // Creating svg stub
    var graphContainer = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg") 
        .attr("id", "graph");
 ...*rest of the code*...
}
```

The problem is that when I call my service from two different browsers at the same time, two svg containers are added. What, I want is that each request gets it's own  elements. How can I achieve this? I know that JavaScript is single threaded, but I would guess that d3 is in the scope of a request not in the scope of the server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you move d3 to be in the scope of the server?

Comment: It behaves the same. In both cases it looks like all client-to-server calls share the same d3 object.

Comment: Also this: when I call the server from the same browser two (or more) times in a row, d3 object stays the same, therefore two (or more) svg elements are added. When I manually remove previously added svg elements, other calls also get responses with removed svg elements (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

d3 should be in the client side code javascript code. 
Just the data should be passed from the server so that the client browser can render the data.
The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673752/d3-js-visualization-with-node-js) question should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file include D3js like this:

```
var d3js = require('d3');
```

In other words don't try to require D3js from inside your request handler.

You can install d3 via npm with:

```
npm install d3
```

Also you may want to update your package.json to include D3js as a dependency