# Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In a project I am collaborating on, we have two choices on which module system we can use:

1. Importing modules using `require`, and exporting using `module.exports` and `exports.foo`.
2. Importing modules using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) `import`, and exporting using ES6 `export`

Are there any performance benefits to using one over the other? Is there anything else that we should know if we were to use ES6 modules over Node.js ones?

Comment: `node --experimental-modules index.mjs` lets you use `import` without Babel and works in Node 8.5.0+. You can (and should) also [publish your npm packages as native ESModule](https://medium.com/@dandv/publishing-native-es-modules-with-node-v8-5-0-730736e0f612), with backwards compatibility for the old `require` way.

Comment: No necessary to use .mjs files, just use type: "module" in your package.json and put extension when importing only for your project files, that's it

Answer (score 966, accepted):

###### Update

Since Node.js v12 (April 2019), support for ES modules is enabled by default, and since Node.js v15 (October 2020) it's stable (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules)). Files, including Node.js modules, must either end in `.mjs` or the nearest `package.json` file must contain `"type": "module"`. The [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) has a ton more information, also about interoperability between [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) and ES modules.

Performance-wise there is always the chance that newer features are not as well optimized as existing features. However, since module files are only evaluated once, the performance aspect can probably be ignored. In the end, you have to run benchmarks to get a definite answer anyway.

ES modules can be loaded dynamically via the `import()` function. Unlike `require`, this returns a promise.

---

###### Previous answer

> Are there any performance benefits to using one over the other?

Keep in mind that there is no JavaScript engine yet that natively supports ES6 modules. You said yourself that you are using [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)). Babel converts `import` and `export` declaration to CommonJS (`require`/`module.exports`) by default anyway. So even if you use ES6 module syntax, you will be using CommonJS under the hood if you run the code in Node.js.

There are technical differences between CommonJS and ES6 modules, e.g., CommonJS allows you to load modules dynamically. ES6 doesn't allow this, [but there is an API in development for that](https://github.com/whatwg/loader).

Since ES6 modules are part of the standard, I would use them.

Comment: @Entei: Seems like you want a default export, not a named export. `module.exports = ...;` is equivalent to `export default ...`. `exports.foo = ...` is equivalent to `export var foo = ...`;

Comment: It's worth noting that even though Babel ultimately transpiles `import` to CommonJS in Node, used alongside Webpack 2 / Rollup (and any other bundler that allows ES6 tree shaking), it's possible to wind up with a file that is significantly smaller than the equivalent code Node crunches through using `require` exactly _because_ of the fact ES6 allows static analysis of import/exports. Whilst this won't make a difference to Node (yet), it certainly can if the code is ultimately going to wind up as a single browser bundle.

Comment: ES6 Modules are in the latest V8 and are also arriving in other browsers behind flags.

See: https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7

Comment: When would you not run your code in Node? Isn't most, if not all, JS these days using NPM, which uses node?

Comment: @stackjlei when it’s embedded in a website? Using npm doesn’t actually mean that the code is executed in node, thanks to module bundlers such as webpack.

Comment: @FelixKling so CommonJS only comes for free if you're using a node server but not if you're using npm for Front End, right?

Comment: Is this answer still true in 2020? Any new updates? @Felix

Comment: @Akhila: Added an update. Let me know if you think that suffices or if I should add more. Thank you for pinging me about this.

Comment: doesn't work: my node program says **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module** when trying **import { countryList } from './countries.mjs'**

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Seems like the file that contains this line isn't recognized as module. Does it have an `.mjs` extensions or does the closest `package.json` file contain `"type": "module"`? See https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system

Comment: @FelixKling Yes it has mjs but not package.json

If i add to package, it works, but i prefer not to do that

Comment: @FelixKling I have a question from a different point of view, can you take a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74690087/what-is-the-problem-of-mixing-require-and-import-in-the-same-typescript-file

Answer (score 230):

There are several usage / capabilities you might want to consider:

Require:

- You can have dynamic loading where the loaded module name isn't
  predefined /static, or where you conditionally load a module only if
  it's "truly required" (depending on certain code flow).
- Loading is
  synchronous. That means if you have multiple `require`s, they are
  loaded and processed one by one.

ES6 Imports:

- You can use
  named imports to selectively load only the pieces you need. That can
  save memory.
- Import can be asynchronous (and in current ES6 Module Loader, it in fact is) and can perform a little better.

Also, the Require module system isn't standard based. It's is highly unlikely to become standard now that ES6 modules exist. In the future there will be native support for ES6 Modules in various implementations which will be advantageous in terms of performance.

Comment: What makes you think ES6 imports are asynchronous?

Comment: @FelixKling - combination of various observations. Using JSPM (ES6 Module Loader...) I noticed that when an import modified the global namespace the effect isn't observed inside other imports (because they occur asynchronously.. This can also be seen in transpiled code). Also, since that is the behavior (1 import doesn't affect others) there no reason not to do so, so it could be implementation dependant

Comment: You mention something very important: module loader. While ES6 provides the import and export syntax, it does not define how modules should be loaded. The important part is that the declarations are statically analyzable, so that dependencies can be determined without executing the code. This would allow a module loader to either load a module synchronously or asynchronously. But ES6 modules by themselves are not synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: @FelixKling ES6 module loader was tagged in the OP so I assume it makes it relevant to the answer. Also I stated that based on observations async is current behavior, as well as possibility in the future (in any implementation) so it's a relevant point to consider. Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I think it's important not to conflate the module system/syntax with the module loader. E.g if you develop for node, then you are likely compiling ES6 modules to `require` anyway, so you are using Node's module system and loader anyway.

Comment: @Amit My mistake. I'm using Babel, not ES6-module-loader

Comment: @kpimov That's fine. I modified the answer anyway after Felix Kling's comments. The async part is not guarenteed to be available (implementation dependant), but possibly will be used.

Comment: @FelixKling - Douglas Crockford in his talk 'The better parts' https://youtu.be/_EF-FO63MXs?t=764 seemed to indicate that the ES6 module imports would be fully asynchronous.

Comment: This answer helped me understand much better, thanks @Amit!

Comment: @Amit can you clarify "You can have dynamic loading where the loaded module name isn't predefined /static, or where you conditionally load a module only if it's "truly required" (depending on certain code flow)." VS asynchronous module loading in es6 modules?

Comment: While require allows dynamic loading, when you use ES6 imports, webpack does tree-shaking and eliminates code which is not being used.

Comment: The major difference between require and import , is that require will automatically scan node_modules to find modules, but import , which comes from ES6, won't. Most people use babel to compile import and export , which makes import act the same as require

Comment: I think an async loader with the presence of a top-level await is a smart thing to do. For example, something like const pkg = pkgload. And if it can easily be determined where the first call/calls are, await there. Or somewhere nearby. Till then, no need to halt the codes. Of course, the implementation might not be easy so maybe they use something like Promise.all(...) instead. (This is probably not how things work and I am just theorizing in this case)

Answer (score 144):

As of right now ES6 import, export is [always compiled to CommonJS](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgCwKYBt0QIxwL5wBmUEIcA5AHQD0amE5AUIwMYQB2AzhOqpVgHMAFHSzYhASglwgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=), so there is **no benefit** using one or other. Although usage of ES6 is recommended since it should be advantageous when native support from browsers released. The reason being, you can import partials from one file while with CommonJS you have to require all of the file.

ES6 → `import, export default, export`

CommonJS → `require, module.exports, exports.foo`

Below is common usage of those.

*ES6 export default*

```
// hello.js
function hello() {
  return 'hello'
}
export default hello

// app.js
import hello from './hello'
hello() // returns hello
```

---

*ES6 export multiple and import multiple*

```
// hello.js
function hello1() {
  return 'hello1'
}
function hello2() {
  return 'hello2'
}
export { hello1, hello2 }

// app.js
import { hello1, hello2 } from './hello'
hello1()  // returns hello1
hello2()  // returns hello2
```

---

*CommonJS module.exports*

```
// hello.js
function hello() {
  return 'hello'
}
module.exports = hello

// app.js
const hello = require('./hello')
hello()   // returns hello
```

---

*CommonJS module.exports multiple*

```
// hello.js
function hello1() {
  return 'hello1'
}
function hello2() {
  return 'hello2'
}
module.exports = {
  hello1,
  hello2
}

// app.js
const hello = require('./hello')
hello.hello1()   // returns hello1
hello.hello2()   // returns hello2
```

Comment: You actually can use `Object Destructuring` when using CommonJS require as well. So you could have: `const { hello1, hello2 } = require("./hello");` and it will be **somewhat** similar to using import/export.

Comment: This is by far the best answer as it provides not only the description, but also the actual code snippets.

Answer (score 48):

The main advantages are syntactic:

- More declarative/compact syntax
- ES6 modules will basically make UMD (Universal Module Definition) obsolete - essentially removes the schism between CommonJS and AMD (server vs browser).

You are unlikely to see any performance benefits with ES6 modules. You will still need an extra library to bundle the modules, even when there is full support for ES6 features in the browser.

Comment: Could you clarify why one needs a bundler even when browsers has full ES6 module support?

Comment: Apologies, edited to make more sense. I meant that the import/export modules feature is not implemented in any browsers natively. A transpiler is still required.

Comment: It seems a bit contradictory frased to me. If there is **full support** then what is the purpose of the bundler? Is there something missing in the ES6 spec? What would the bundler actually do that isn't available in a **fully supported environment**?

Comment: As @snozza said..."the import/export modules feature is not implemented in any browsers naively. A transpiler is still required"

Comment: As I understand it, ES6 browser support now means you can use the simpler JavaScript module syntax (`export` and `import`) natively in [most modern browsers](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module). Unless you still need to write for IE9. Correct me if I've missed something glaringly obvious, but I can use ES6 modules (say) in Chrome running node's http-server with no other library.

Comment: You no longer need any extra libraries. Since v8.5.0 (released more than a year ago), `node --experimemntal-modules index.mjs` lets you use `import` without Babel. You can (and should) also [publish your npm packages as native ESModule, with backwards compatibility](https://medium.com/@dandv/publishing-native-es-modules-with-node-v8-5-0-730736e0f612) for the old `require` way. Many browsers also support [dynamic imports](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) natively.

Answer (score 39):

> Are there any performance benefits to using one over the other?

The current answer is no, because none of the current browser engines implements `import/export` from the ES6 standard.

Some comparison charts http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ don't take this into account, so when you see almost all greens for Chrome, just be careful. `import` keyword from ES6 hasn't been taken into account.

In other words, current browser engines including V8 cannot import *new JavaScript file* from the *main JavaScript file* via any JavaScript directive.

( We may be still just [a few bugs away](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5685) or years away until V8 implements that according to the ES6 specification. )

This [document](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) is what we need, and this [document](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-imports) is what we must obey.

And the ES6 standard said that the module dependencies should be there  before we read the module like in the programming language C, where we had (headers) `.h` files.

This is a good and well-tested structure, and I am sure the experts that created the ES6 standard had that in mind.

This is what enables Webpack or other package bundlers to optimize the bundle in some *special* cases, and reduce some dependencies from the bundle that are not needed. But in cases we have perfect dependencies this will never happen.

It will need some time until `import/export` native support goes live, and the `require` keyword will not go anywhere for a long time.

What is `require`?

This is `node.js` way to load modules. ( https://github.com/nodejs/node )

Node uses system-level methods to read files. You basically rely on that when using `require`. `require` will end in some system call like `uv_fs_open` (depends on the end system, Linux, Mac, Windows) to load JavaScript file/module.

To check that this is true, try to use Babel.js, and you will see that the `import` keyword will be converted into `require`.

[image]

Comment: Actually, there's one area where performance *could* be improved -- bundle size. Using `import` in a Webpack 2 / Rollup build process can potentially reduce the resulting file size by 'tree shaking' unused modules/code, that might otherwise wind up in the final bundle. Smaller file size = faster to download = faster to init/execute on the client.

Comment: the reasoning was no current browser on the planet earth allows the `import ` keyword natively. Or this means you cannot import another JavaScript file from a JavaScript file. This is why you cannot compare performance benefits of these two. 
But of course, tools like Webpack1/2 or Browserify can deal with compression. They are neck to neck: https://gist.github.com/substack/68f8d502be42d5cd4942

Comment: You're overlooking 'tree shaking'. Nowhere in your gist link is tree shaking discussed. Using ES6 modules enables it, because `import` and `export` are static declarations that import a specific code path, whereas `require` can be dynamic and thus bundle in code that's not used. The performance benefit is indirect-- Webpack 2 and/or Rollup can _potentially_ result in smaller bundle sizes that are faster to download, and therefore appear snappier to the end user (of a browser). This only works if all code is written in ES6 modules and therefore imports can be statically analysed.

Comment: I updated the answer @LeeBenson, I think if we consider the native support  from browser engines we cannot compare yet. What comes as handy three shaking option using the Webpack, may also be achieved even before we set the CommonJS modules, since for most of the real applications we know what modules should be used.

Comment: Your answer is totally valid, but I think we're comparing two different characteristics. _All_ `import/export` is converted to `require`, granted. But what happens _before_ this step could be considered "performance" enhancing. Example: If `lodash` is written in ES6 and you `import { omit } from lodash`, the ultimate bundle will ONLY contain 'omit' and not the other utilities, whereas a simple `require('lodash')` will import everything. This will increase the bundle size, take longer to download, and therefore decrease performance. This is only valid in a browser context, of course.

Comment: _"since for most of the real applications we know what modules should be used"_ - that's true for your own modules, but when importing packages from npm, you probably don't know much about the internals. If the source is written using ES6 import/export, and you only include what you _know_ you need, Webpack 2/Roll up can often omit what you don't need because it can statically analyse the source before transpiling. Again, I'm talking about situations where the target is a browser bundle and you care about the size of that bundle. I've had 5mb+ reduced to 500kb in practice.

Comment: We are on the same page, `import` notation is handy and allows you to be more specific, which bundlers like.  I cannot point at the moment to any tool that would do *three shaking* thing for the CommonJS modules that are not loaded dynamically. But I imagine this is possible via statical analysis of the code in use.

Comment: This answer is out of date. [All modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) support `import`, and Chrome&Safari also support [dynamic imports](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) natively.

Answer (score 38):

Using ES6 modules can be useful for 'tree shaking'; i.e. enabling Webpack 2, Rollup (or other bundlers) to identify code paths that are not used/imported, and therefore don't make it into the resulting bundle. This can significantly reduce its file size by eliminating code you'll never need, but with CommonJS is bundled by default because Webpack et al have no way of knowing whether it's needed.

This is done using static analysis of the code path.

For example, using:

```
import { somePart } 'of/a/package';
```

... gives the bundler a hint that `package.anotherPart` isn't required (if it's not imported, it can't be used- right?), so it won't bother bundling it.

To enable this for Webpack 2, you need to ensure that your transpiler isn't spitting out CommonJS modules. If you're using the `es2015` plug-in with babel, you can disable it in your `.babelrc` like so:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { modules: false }],
  ]
}
```

[Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) and others may work differently - view the docs if you're interested.

Comment: also great for tree shaking http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html

Comment: What does happen with `require` then?

Answer (score 32):

When it comes to async or maybe lazy loading, then `import ()` is much more powerful. See when we require the component in asynchronous way, then we use `import` it in some async manner as in `const` variable using `await`.

```
const module = await import('./module.js');
```

Or if you want to use `require()` then,

```
const converter = require('./converter');
```

Thing is `import()` is actually async in nature. As mentioned by neehar venugopal in [ReactConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb6RCrDaxhw), you can use it to dynamically load React components for client-side architecture.

Also it is way better when it comes to Routing. That is the one special thing that makes network log to download a necessary part when user connects to specific website to its specific component. E.g., login page before dashboard wouldn't download all components of dashboard. Because what is needed currently, i.e., the login component, only that will be downloaded.

The same goes for `export`: ES6 `export` are exactly same as for CommonJS `module.exports`.

***Note***: If you are developing a Node.js project, then you have to strictly use `require()` as Node.js will throw exception error as `invalid token 'import'`  if you will use `import`. So Node.js does not support import statements.

***Update*** - As suggested by [Dan Dascalescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu): Since v8.5.0 (released Sep 2017), `node --experimental-modules index.mjs` lets you use `import` without Babel. You can (and should) also [publish your npm packages as a native ES Module, with backwards compatibility](https://medium.com/@dandv/publishing-native-es-modules-with-node-v8-5-0-730736e0f612)  for the old `require` way.

See this for more clearance where to use async imports: *[Neehar Venugopal - A Beginner's Guide to Code Splitting Your React App - React Conf 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb6RCrDaxhw)*

Comment: So will the require be sync and wait?

Comment: Can say factually!

Answer (score 19):

The most important thing to know is that ES6 modules are, indeed, an official standard, while CommonJS (Node.js) modules are not.

In 2019, ES6 modules are supported by [84%](https://caniuse.com/#search=module) of browsers. While Node.js puts them behind an [--experimental-modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) flag, there is also a convenient node package called [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm), which makes the integration smooth.

Another issue you're likely to run into between these module systems is code location. Node.js assumes source is kept in a `node_modules` directory, while most ES6 modules are deployed in a flat directory structure. These are not easy to reconcile, but it can be done by hacking your `package.json` file with pre and post installation scripts. Here is an example [isomorphic module](https://github.com/isysd-mirror/iso-test) and an [article](https://medium.com/@iravagecoins/isomorphic-es6-node-js-module-boilerplate-w-universal-testing-bb962f02670d) explaining how it works.

Answer (score 11):

I personally use import because, we can import the required methods, members by using import.

```
import {foo, bar} from "dep";
```

*FileName:* dep.js

```
export foo function(){};
export const bar = 22
```

Credit goes to Paul Shan. [More info](http://voidcanvas.com/import-vs-require/).

Comment: Great choice! Are you also [publishing your npm packages as native ESModule, with backwards compatibility](https://medium.com/@dandv/publishing-native-es-modules-with-node-v8-5-0-730736e0f612) for the old `require` way?

Comment: you can do the same with require!

Comment: `const {a,b} = require('module.js'); ` works as well ... if you export `a` and `b`

Comment: `module.exports = { a: ()={}, b: 22 }` - The second part of @BananaAcid respones

Answer (score 5):

- ES modules are static, which means that imports are described at the top level of every module and outside any control flow statement. This will not work:

  ```
  if (condition) {
     import module1 from 'module1'
  }
  ```

But it in commonjs, it is allowed:

```
if (condition) {
    module = require('module1')
}
```

- ES modules run implicitly in `strict mode`. This means that we don't have to explicitly add the "use strict" statements at the beginning of every file. Strict mode cannot be disabled; therefore, we cannot use undeclared variables or the with statement or have other features that are only available in non-strict mode. `strict mode` is a safer execution mode.
- In ESM, some important CommonJS references are not defined. These include
  `require , exports , module.exports , __filename,` and `__dirname`.
- We can import CommonJS modules from ESM by using the standard import syntax. But only `default exports` work:

  ```
     import packageName from 'commonjs-package' // Works
    import { moduleName } from 'commonjs-package' // Errors
  ```

But, it is not possible to import ES modules from CommonJS modules.

- ESM cannot import JSON files directly as modules, a feature that is used quite frequently with CommonJS. That is why in reactjs `fetch` api is used.

  ```
  import data from './data.json' //fails
  ```

Comment: [import data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" }](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68593192/9935654)

Comment: You _can_ import module conditionally with [dynamic import](https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions#dynamic-import()).

Comment: You can import JSON files directly now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why (probably optimization - lazy loading?) is it working like that, but I have noticed that `import` may not parse code if imported modules are not used.
Which may not be expected behaviour in some cases.

Take hated Foo class as our sample dependency.

*foo.ts*

```
export default class Foo {}
console.log('Foo loaded');
```

For example:

*index.ts*

```
import Foo from './foo'
// prints nothing
```

*index.ts*

```
const Foo = require('./foo').default;
// prints "Foo loaded"
```

*index.ts*

```
(async () => {
    const FooPack = await import('./foo');
    // prints "Foo loaded"
})();
```

On the other hand:

*index.ts*

```
import Foo from './foo'
typeof Foo; // any use case
// prints "Foo loaded"
```