# import vs require in node.js coding

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've just start an express project and want to use ES6 for both server and client. Currently I'm using a mixed style of `require` and `import`.

Should I use `import` over `require` in es6 project? Will `import` replace `require` in the future? If I want to use `import` and `export` in pure es6 way, which `export` syntax should I use?

Comment: ES6 modules are second-class citizens, it depends on what you need, and what tool you use, ie. jspm, Babel, etc. I'd stick to first-class Common modules for the time being, until the ES6 loader standard is finalized.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export