# How does React Native require(moduleName) work?

Tags: node.js, react-native, commonjs

I saw code like `var Animated = require('Animated')` in react-native source code. But how can this be resolved without a path ?
My guess is that will be preprocessed by the packager by something like registering and I would like to do this in my own project. But there seems to be no document for react-native's packager , and I can't find the source code where this "registering" happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find it! Just add `@providesModule moduleName` in the file's comment in the header , look into [issue 896](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/896) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
  Animated,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
```

i can't catch what you said.but i post the above snippet how i used.

Comment: 'react-native' is a npm package so you can import from it without path. But in most case we just want to import a js file in our own project. which may look like import {...} from {../../../core/logic/whatever}. And once you move the target to somewhere else, everything is broken.

Comment: how about this                                                                                             var Animated = require('../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Animated.js')

Comment: What I am asking is how to use that like require('Animated') without a path. That is exactly how react-native source code do. Something happen because their internal tool haste.

Comment: [some relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143147/requiring-modules-in-react-native) wait for your resolution.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how `haste` work, there is nearly no document at all .