# Create index file full of exports react-native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible in react native to create an index file from which you can refer to for imports rather than doing '../../folder/component'?

I have tried a few different methods, including the following:

components folder

```
-> chat
  -> Chat.js
-> dashboard
  -> Dashboard.js
-> home
  -> Home.js
-> index.js
```

index.js

```
import Home from './home/Home'
import Dashboard from './dashboard/Dashboard'
import Chat from './chat/Chat'

module.exports = {
    Home,
    Dashboard,
    Chat,
}
```

Then inside a component, lets say Dashboard,
`import { Home, Chat } from '../components'`

Another method:

index.js

```
export Home from './home/Home'
export Dashboard from './dashboard/Dashboard'
export Chat from './chat/Chat'
```

I also tried surrounding the export with curlies, ex `export { Home } from './home/Home'` because the compiler threw an error otherwise, but it still did not work this way.

I also tried the method inside this users question [Requiring Modules in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143147/requiring-modules-in-react-native)

Is this functionality possible in react-native?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Do the following.

Do named exports from Component files.

from Home.js

```
export { Home };
```

from Chat.js

```
export { Chat };
```

from Dashboard.js

```
export { Dashboard };
```

where Home, Chat and Dashboard are the components names in the respective files.

Now in your index.js Do following:

```
export * from './home/Home';
export * from './chat/Chat';
export * from './dashboard/Dashboard';
```

use them in other files like this:

```
import { Home, Chat, Dashboard } from '../components'
```

**Update 1**

If you are using redux and want to export the component which is connected to the store, then use the following:

Store the connected component in a const variable like this:

```
const HomeComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

then export it like this:

```
export { HomeComponent }
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this in this case where I am using redux and my export statement for my component looks like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)`? Wrapping Home in {} throws error, ex. `connect(...)({Home})`

Comment: connect is an HOC (higher order component) which returns a component. So store that in a const variable like this: const HomeComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home) and then write export { HomeComponent }. That should work. I haven't tested that. Can you try that please.

Comment: @wizloc please tell if that worked for you or not. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work, but I will take another look on Monday and see what the issue is

Comment: I tried the above suggested method (storing the connected component in a variable and exporting it using named export) and its working for me. Hope it works for you as well

Comment: @wizloc have you found the solution?

Comment: I am using your method. `export { Home }`, then inside index.js `export * from '/home/Home` and inside the component I want to use it `import { Home } from '../components'`. I then try to use <Home /> in the render of the component I import it in but I get error `Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function. Check the render method of...`

Comment: I see my error. I was doing export default { Home }. Removing default keyword makes it work. Thanks

Comment: great. I will update the answer to include these details as well :)