# Export statement for a class in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node currently enables class construction in Strict mode.

If I have the following class:

```
"use strict"

 class MyClass {
   constructor(foo) {
     this.foo = foo
   }

   func(){/*ETC */}
 }
```

What is the corresponding export statement for it to be exportable to another module. What about the import statement from another file?

Comment: See [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31367852/816620).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would currently "import" or "export" anything else currently in node, using commonJS `require` and `module.exports`:

`Foo.js`

```
class Foo {}
module.exports = Foo
// or if you want to edit additional objects:
// module.exports.Foo = Foo
// module.exports.theNumberThree = 3
```

`Bar.js`

```
var Foo = require("./Foo")
var foo = new Foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really an issue with how much Node supports ES6 modules. While it currently allows for classes, the import/export features of ES6 are not implemented yet, and relies more on CommonJS require.

To export use the following:

```
//MyClass.js
class MyClass {
   constructor(foo) {
     this.foo = foo
   }

   func(){/*ETC */}
 }

 module.exports = function(foo){
   return new MyObject(foo);
 }
```

To Import:

```
//in app.js

var myClass = require('./MyClass');
var mc = new myClass(foo);
```