# ES6 code on Nodejs 4.x : Is V8 4.5 a native JS engine that runs ES6 directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to upgrade a micro service that's on Nodejs 1.0.x to Nodejs 4.x.
The purpose is to enhance the functionality of this service & take advantage of ES6 features, especially avoid prototype clutter in new code segment.
While going through few blogs, I've come across a statement that ES6's module pattern is standardised and it's Asynchronous unlike require().

If the module loading is Asynchronous(with import of module syntax), I'm trying to understand how the code in that file take advantage of this feature? All the code that have dependency on this asynchronously imported module will also become asynchronous? If yes, instead of combination of require (synchronous) and import/module (asynchronous), I would like to change every thing to import/module assuming the performance gain.

I need some help in correcting or fine-tuning my thought process.

Comment: es6 import is not async.

Comment: "*I've come across a statement*" Can you share your source?

Comment: Following is the reference: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 modules are loaded synchronously in Node.js (server). They are loaded asynchronously only in the browser. The advantage of import is that it's the same keyword for both use cases.

Comment: No browser supports ES6 module loading right now. There are implementations of module loaders - some are asynchronous, some are not.