# what is a import satement in nodejs instead of require

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gameclosure

I was going through [this module](https://github.com/gameclosure/timestep), and found many of the files using the import stament.ex: [this one](https://github.com/gameclosure/timestep/blob/master/src/Sound.js).
can anybody tell me how the import statement is replacing the standerd require statement of nodejs and how are they working?

EDIT:
 this is not the duplicate, because the import syntax is different form the ES6 syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: is this the es6 module feature? because the systax seems different, in the example i have mentioned, it <imports 'file' as var> whereas in es6 it <imports var from 'file'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import statement is provided by [js.io](https://github.com/gameclosure/js.io) - A module system that the repository is using.

Quoting from the README of the project:

> js.io is a multi-platform package management and module system for
>   JavaScript. js.io modules can be evaluated in a JavaScript runtime
>   (e.g. node.js) or precompiled into a single package for use on the
>   client side.
>
> js.io provides the following:
>
> A module system. Dependency graph that works in the client and the
>   browser. Support and networking libraries that can be used on either
>   platform.

The import statement as in the linked example does not confirm to ES6 spec.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), the syntax for ES6 imports follow the following patterns:

> ```
> import name from "module-name";
> import * as name from "module-name";
> import { member } from "module-name";
> import { member as alias } from "module-name";
> import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
> import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
> import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
> import defaultMember, * as alias from "module-name";
> import defaultMember from "module-name";
> import "module-name";
> ```

The usage `import AudioManager as exports;` is not a valid usage as per the above rules.

I could not deduce from the README of js.io if confirmance with ES6 modules is a goal of the project.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i have one more question, that is,  is there any way that this file can be browserified without the jsio lib?

Comment: i dont think so. you should be able to compile the library using jsio once and use browserify for the rest of your application though.

Comment: do you have any idea about which part code is responsible for the import statement in the jsio?

Comment: Code here is responsible for parsing of import statement: https://github.com/gameclosure/js.io/blob/bf8cdfa2c19fd610b179ce47ca7101f36988c7e9/packages/preprocessors/import.js The export resolution and building functionality is available here: https://github.com/gameclosure/js.io/blob/bf8cdfa2c19fd610b179ce47ca7101f36988c7e9/packages/preprocessors/compiler.js#L14

Comment: can you tell me what is the syntax  "/^(\s*)(import\s+[^=+*"'\r\n;\/]+|from\s+[^=+"'\r\n;\/ ]+\s+import\s+[^=+"'\r\n;\/]+)(;|\/|$)/gm;" used in the importExpr variable called?

Comment: This is a javascript regular expression used to parse the import syntax. Details about usage of regular expressions in javascript are available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and to understand this particular regular expression you can use the following online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/mS3wW4/1