# What am I doing wrong in my ESLint file so import will not be alerted?

Tags: alert, babeljs, eslint, eslintrc, babel-eslint

After reading a few Q&As regarding my issue of:

> Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType:
>   module'

- [ignore ESLint error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158552/ignore-eslint-error-import-and-export-may-only-appear-at-the-top-level)
- [What is the correct way of using import and require in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346122/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-import-and-require-in-es6)
- [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Wait what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-w)

I wrote my *.eslintrc.json* to:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "plugin:node/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "spaced-comment": "off",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "func-names": "off",
    "object-shorthand": "off",
    "no-process-exit": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "no-return-await": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "prefer-destructuring": ["error", { "object": true, "array": false }],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "req|res|next|val" }],
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"]
  }
}
```

using the devDependencies of:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  },
```

and also setting my engine:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10"
  }
```

When I write a test module with Babel:

```
export default class Search {
  constructor() {
    alert('search test')
  }
}
```

I get the alert of:

> Import and export declarations are not supported
>   yet.eslint(node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax)

Why are my settings not working? I could write an ignore of `modules/` in an *.eslintignore* file but I'd like to know why I'm getting this alert and how I can resolve it correctly?

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 7):

There probably is a better way to do it but this worked for me.

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "plugin:node/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "spaced-comment": "off",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "func-names": "off",
    "object-shorthand": "off",
    "no-process-exit": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "no-return-await": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "prefer-destructuring": ["error", { "object": true, "array": false }],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "req|res|next|val" }],
    "node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": [
      "error",
      {
        "version": ">=13.0.0",
        "ignores": ["modules"]
      }
    ],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      {
        "js": "ignorePackages"
      }
    ]
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
}
```

The key here is the rule 'node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax'. All I am doing here is overriding this rule added by 'plugin:node/recommended' to allow ES modules syntax.

Answer (score 5):

As @joan Gil said ,try to use `"type":"module"` on your `package.json` (as long as you are using node > 12)

Comment: speaking about `package.json` it is also a good practice to specify the version of node that your project works on e.g.:
`"engines": {
        "node": ">=8.10.0"
   }`

Answer (score -1):

Check your .eslintrc file.
It might be because of the node/recommended plugin.
`"extends": ["plugin:node/recommended"]`

Comment: you can do that but it is analogous to situation when you turn off error logging to do not see it anymore. In other words you didn't resolve the issue you just hide it.

Answer (score -6):

I Just had the same issue, removing 
`"plugin:node/recommended"`
did it for me.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. Removing the plugin will actually exclude its rules from ESLint. Basically it means not installing it at all, which is not recommended. 
I suggest taking a look at the plugin documentation https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node. For this one case I think it's missing the "type": "module" in the package.json. Adding "plugin:node/recommended-module"  to the list of plugins might also work