# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, node-modules

I am trying to create my first electron app. When calling npm start from the terminal, I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')...

at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25).

This is my package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "main.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/Falcon-JasonM/2024_electron_sandbox.git",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^28.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my main script:

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
import {magicEightBall} from './chapter3.mjs';
const { app, BrowserWindow } = import('electron')
const path = import('node:path')


function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  
  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  {createWindow();
    magicEightBall();}

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

I'll admit to probably crossing some wires in the process of trying to import a second JS script, chapter3.mjs, into the main.mjs file. Can anyone tell me the proper way to rewire this so that both scripts run when I enter npm start in the command line, and the browser window launches?

Comment: `const { app, BrowserWindow } = import('electron')` looks suspect. Try `import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';`

Comment: `import('electron')` is a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#importing_defaults) statement.  It would have to be `const { app, BrowserWindow } = await import('electron');` for it to do anything interesting, and it's likely unnecessary.

Comment: This was the problem. I was trying to mix/match ways of adding script. It's working now. Thanks for the replies all

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be with how you mix the different ways of doing imports. Try using named imports for all of them:

```js
import { magicEightBall } from './chapter3.mjs';
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import path from 'node:path';
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601582/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-const-and-which-is-preferred-in-common) gives some more explanation on the difference between import and const.