# ES6 import "module" don't give acces to function of "module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use ES6 imorts with babel and Node.js

```
import "./utils.js";

log("something"); //throw an error : log is not defined
```

My `utils.js` look like this :

```
function log(... params){
    console.log(... params);
}

log("module utils executed");
//Is executed and display "module utils executed" in the console.
```

I have also tryed to use `export function log(... params)` and `export default log(... params)` but it doesn't works.

So I don't understand how this is suppose to works...

EDIT:

I know that an other way to import is to do `import utils from "./utils.js"`

But it's not what I want. I want to be able to use `log()` without prefixing it with the module variable name. Like in [this blog post](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth#import)

Comment: Have you tried `export default function log() { ...`?

Comment: Yes I have tried. And it doesn't change any thing.

Comment: Can you point to the place in the blog post where you saw functions are imported directly into the namespace?

Comment: If you click on m'y link you will directly be scrolled to the correct anchor "#import"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to import all exported members of a module into the current namespace. Importing a module for side effects (i.e. `import 'utils'`) does nothing with the members of `utils`.

The closest you can get is something like this:

**utils.js**

```
export function log(...params) { ... }
export function foo(a) { ... }
```

**main.js**

```
import * as u from './utils';
u.log(1, 2, 3);
u.foo(4);
```

or

```
import { log, foo } from './utils';
log(1, 2, 3);
foo(4);
```

One of the design goals of the ES6 module spec is a static module structure, which allows resolution of imports at compile time (before executing anything). Allowing blanket imports would make static analysis more difficult.

---

**EDIT** (*do not do this!*)

As @Bergi pointed out in the comments, you can add functions to the global namespace  as follows:

**utils.js**

```
function log(...params) { ... }
global.log = log;
```

**main.js**

```
import './utils';  // import for side effects, add properties to the global object
log(1, 2, 3);      // the global object is in the scope chain, so this is resolved
```

However **this is a bad idea**. Global variables are slow to resolve and in general break the modularity you try to achieve by using modules in the first place.

Comment: Well we could put the functions in global scope and then just import that module, but that's really what we don't want to do.

Comment: @Bergi, you mean with `global.log = ...`? Yes, that would be a pretty awful thing to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, it's the only way the OP's code (in `main.js`) would work as-is. But +1 for your answer to how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 6):

there Different ES6 `import` and Node.js `require` [Question Describe The Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

**In case** you will use Node.js `require`:

your `utils.js` File will be

```
function log(params) {
    console.log(params);
}

module.exports = {
   log
};
```

The other File will import your Utils Module will be

```
var utils = require('./utils');
utils.log("test");
```

**In case** you will use ES6 Modules:

your `utils.js` File will be

```
var log = function (params) {
    console.log(params);
}

var utils = {
    log: log
}

export default utils;
```

The other File will import your Utils Module will be

```
import utils from 'utils';

utils.log("test");
```

**UPDATE**

According to [your Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955456/es6-import-module-dont-give-acces-to-function-of-module#comment57643805_34955853), Yes you can do this But using ES6 Module

your `utils.js` File will be

```
function log(params) {
    console.log(params);
}

function anotherLog(params) {
    console.log(params);
}

export { log, anotherLog }
```

The other File will import your Utils Module will be

```
import { log } from 'utils';

log("test");
```

Comment: Yes I know this but I don't want to use this import type. I want to import functions directly in my namespace. I want to be able to call `log` without prefixing it with module variable.

Comment: Yes it works for `log` but my `utils.js` module doesn't conatins only `log()`. It's a util module that will contains functions that I want to use in all my modules.

Comment: you can export many functions inside of `utils`, and then selectively import with `import { log } from 'utils';`

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin see my update again, you will export all function into your Util Module using `export` Keyword and you can import only method what you want to use using `import` Keyword

Comment: But I will have to put the list of functions I need. There is no way to use the syntax I have tryed ? I have seen this syntax in other exemples.