# Does React Native use require or import?

Tags: react-native

Does React Native use `require` or `import`?

All I can find is an old tutorial using `require()`, but when I run `react-native init`, I'm getting a project that uses `import`. Is this due to recent changes in React Native?

What are the main differences?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes the latest React Native tutorials and examples use the new `import` syntax.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html

In terms of the differences between CommonJS (require) and ES6 modules (import), there are some good answers here:

[Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

I think most people prefer the new ES6 syntax.  However no JS engines implement ES6 modules currently, so it needs to be converted by an ES6 transpiler (e.g. Babel) to `require` statements.  React Native is setup to do this out of the box, so you can just start using `import` and it should just work.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference is, that `import` is ECMAScript 6 syntax and `require` is ECMAScript 5. Both are interchangeable, but import has a nice syntax for renaming: `export { MY_CONST as THE_CONST, myFunc as theFunc };`.

Answer (score 5):

React Native now uses Babel for "modules" compilation ([doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html)). If scaffold an app with `create-react-native-app`, in folder `node_modules`, there is [the Babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs) named

```
babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
```

, which is referenced across the app.

As name implies, this plugin just transforms ES2015 modules syntax to CommonJS.

For the main differences, I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31355008/2909851) appearing in another post.