# Calling a method of a parent component from child - React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

I'm developing my first app and still learning the flow.
So suppose I have a component called:

Parent which holds a method HelloWorld() like the following example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {
    Helloworld() {
        console.log('Hello world');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View>{this.props.children}</View>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Parent;
```

and then i want to import this in to another component and use its method then how do I do it? 
Ill write another short example of how I would implement it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Parent } from 'path to parent'; 
//or
const Parent = require('path to parent');
//which of these is better?

class Home extends Component {
    Helloworld() {
        console.log('Hello world');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Parent>
                // this is what i need
                <Button onClick={parent.Helloword()}>Some Button</Button>
            </Parent>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you should pass info from parent to child through props.

parent.jsx:

```
import Child from './child';

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.helloWorld = this.helloWorld.bind(this);
    }

    helloWorld() {
        console.log('Hello world!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View><Child method={this.helloWorld} /></View>
        );
    }
}
```

child.jsx:

```
class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={this.props.method} />
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: about preference between `import` and `require`, I believe it's a matter of taste, but I think `import` is cleaner.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. I havent had time to test this but i will asap and give you feed back.

Comment: There's another difference about import and require I forgot to mention: `import` can only be used at beginning of the files, while `require` can be used anywhere.

Comment: both of the answers here work but i find this one is a little more tailored to what I need. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can read [React Native-Tutorial-What's going on here?](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#what-s-going-on-here) about `import`. and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266515/does-react-native-use-require-or-import)

Comment: Ill mark your answer up but not mark it as an answer as its only half of this question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass a **prop** in the child class: 
And then call it from the child: **this.props.propName()**
We can pass string, numbers, functions, array, objects in **prop**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

var Parent = React.createClass({   
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Child foo={()=>this.func1()} bar={()=>this.func2()} />
    );
  },
  func1: function(){
    //the func does not return a renderable component
    console.log('Printed from the parent!');
  }
  func2: function(){
    //the func returns a renderable component
    return <Text>I come from parent!</Text>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({   
  render: function() {
    this.props.foo();
    return (
      <Text>Dummy</Text>
      {this.props.bar()}
    );
  },
});

module.exports = Parent;
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. I havent had time to test this but i will asap and give you feed back.

Comment: this answer also is fine just the above answer is more tailored to what i need. Thank you