# How to determine how to import a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

Right now I'm importing modules into node project as

> import * as name from "moduleName";

Im not doing it as

> var name = require("moduleName");

as we used to be in the node project, earlier

my question is there difference in the writing a module when we import using require or import, are modules written internally are same just we are importing in different way or its something internal that forces us to use require or import when importing

and what is the difference between require and import(es6)

Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) and [this](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/nodejs-require-vs-es6-import-export.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Comment: what I understood with both links, that for import module using require we need to export differently than importing ES6, it means we need some modifications in module for importing

Comment: So we can first see how module is exported and than import the way it is or we can use both imports no matter what implementation is

Answer (score 1):

1. import runs at the beginning of the file and it would be already
   loaded before the code itself runs.
2. require on the other hand is run
   inline and can be inserted within the code conditionally.

Comment: what do you mean by run inline and can be inserted within the code conditionally

Comment: var module1 = require("module1"); is written within the block of code such as an if /else and not at the top like import statements. Therefore the loading order of modules differ.

Comment: right, then there is difference between module implementation for import using require and es6 import? or no matter whatever the implementation but we can import them using es6