# Can I use es6 style module import in nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using the latest nodejs version, but am still getting an error while using es6 module import.

I could also find on a blog that node doesn't yet support es6 import module.
https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/ - *no JavaScript runtime currently supports ES Modules*.
I am new to javascript and node, is anyone using es6 module import with nodejs, without transpiling the code to lower js versions.

Comment: It's not implemented, so you cannot "use" it. "without transpiling the code to lower js versions" --- in case of es2015 modules it's not "lower version", it's a "supported APIs" instead.

Comment: thanks, for confirming. please move this comment in answer section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Answer (score 13):

You can if you are willing to use a tool like Babel.

```
npm i -D babel babel-cli babel-core babel-preset-es2015
```

Create a file `.babelrc` and put the following in it:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And then in `package.json` in the `scripts` section do some thing like this:

```
"dev": "babel src -d dist && node dist/your_file.js"
```

This will transpile all of the code in a directory named `src/` but it in a directory called `dist/`, and then run the file you specify.

It can then be used via the command as follows:

```
npm dev
```

Comment: Or use babel-node for running scripts

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2019:**
import / export statements are supported in node v12.
Right now behind the `--experimental-modules` flag. 
Which is supposed to be removed this October.