# When should I use export or require to use react-native?

Tags: javascript, import, react-native, requirejs

I'm newbie to react native. Recently I've seen some tutorials about it. There is something vague for me.

Sometimes react will be added to the project like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
```

And sometimes else it will be done like this:

```
var React = require('react-native');
```

Are these equivalent? If not, when exactly should I use which one?

Comment: import are ES6 based while require is is a common node require syntax, Its just an way of importing libraries

Comment: It has nothing to do with react. They do the same, at the very top level, but Imports were added in ES6, since it supports native modules. 
There are more technical differences, like import can be asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)