# Differences between require and import in react-native

Tags: react-native

I believe understand the syntactic differences between `require` and `import`. I extensively use `import` with default or partial module dependencies. However in the `react-native` main codebase [require it is still being used](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/05ec85043b86fa94408e7a72b55123a60c90426c#diff-a562e4a7ac9e900c6d2bc644453e9152R18).

I'd like to implement some kind of lazy-load or at least make the application loading faster, and I understand there might be some relationship between how modules are packed / imported and used to load module chunks into memory.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Latest React Native tutorials and examples use the new `import` syntax.

Require is `ECMAScript 5`, while import is the latest `ES6` format used commonly now.

for Comparison refer: [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)