# React using import vs. required

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning react and I have an app using webpack, babel and react. It seems react has two ways of writing it using either `required` or `import`. It also seems there is a lot more documentation on using `import`. How can I change my stack to use the import version?

Comment: I think you want to know difference between `require` and `import`.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Answer (score 5):

The [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statements are an ES6 standard. Right now, your setup is likely using Babel to transpile this into ES5. You can use one or the other, but import/export will soon become the standard, so adopting it is advised.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`import` is ES6 (or ES2015) standard. To use it, you need to install and activate the preset in babel.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your project folder then type this: `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env`
2. Create a file named `.babelrc` (in case you have not created one) and insert this lines:

   `{
     'presets': ['env', 'react']
   }`

I assume you have setup the webpack to work with babel.