# Accessing a function from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Javascript files, a `main.js` which loads first and then a `secondary.js` which loads afterwards. What I am trying to do is create a global function in `main.js` which can be utilized on the pages where `secondary.js` is loaded.

Here's what I have in `main.js`:

```
var doSomething;

doSomething = function() {
    //things to do
}
```

And then in my `secondary.js`:

```
var result = doSomething();
```

However, this is returning `doSomething is not defined`. I searched SO and found similar questions but was not able to find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Redfx I don't think this a duplicate of that target.

Comment: Using node you will need to use require(). In browser you will need to either include both files in the correct order OR use a module loader (like SystemJS).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Have you read through the answer? It tells you how to import another js inside a js

Comment: I am not trying to import another js inside a js, I'm trying to create and access a global function.

Comment: fairly common in node-apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Comment: To try to access a function inside another file, you kinda have to import it. Otherwise how can it see?

Comment: @Redfx You don't work with js much do you? Good practice or not, directly calling a function from another file is very common in the real world.

Comment: I can create a global variable that can be accessed from another Javascript file without importing it through js, just trying to do that same thing but with a function. I am not using Node either.

Comment: @csm_dev oh then that 3200 voted answer counts nothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Is this Node or a browser here?

Comment: @csm_dev and no, i do not work with plain js without any framework and I always had to import

Comment: Check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/vidQBnhASJ71ftEANPmn?p=preview

Comment: "_main.js which loads first and then a secondary.js which loads afterwards_" Show us your example of this.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Yours question is far too unclear currently.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I was defining the function within document ready and I was trying to access it outside of document ready. Thanks for all the responses everyone!

Comment: This is why MCVE exists... That being said, thank you for coming back to let us know instead of just running off :)

Comment: As mentioned creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would of saved everyone wasting their time here...

Comment: @Redfx calling a global function defined in another file doesn't require imports.  if you dont work with plain js, maybe listen to the people who have?

Comment: Hi @Amy thank you for your spare time to read through all comments. He did not post any HTML, and I didnt insist on anything. I just told by my experience. Btw, if he doesnt import the scripts inside html, would it be able to still find the method? Without no connection in anyway ? I'm asking to learn

Comment: @Redfx linking to the script from an html file doesn't qualify as "imports".  That's a module term.  Also "oh then that 3200 voted answer counts nothing" is absolutely insisting on something using sarcasm.

Comment: @Amy Well A plain js file would never be able to see a method inside another one without any link between. I cannot tell if he is using a framework or linking through HTML. So I am not totally wrong, neither those guys. I was commenting through what was given on the question, no offence. Which loads the 'script' files and acts as a one file -> thus it sees the method right? By not knowing his html or whether he is using a framework or not.. It is kind of aggressive to blame me in this manner.

Comment: Yes, one file can call a function in another file without directly referencing that other file.

Comment: @Redfx no one is "blaming" you for anything.  What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `doSomething is not defined` because `doSomething` is being created after `secondary.js` has been loaded, so it's not available and you are getting a reference error.

**You need to control the order in which your code is getting executed.**

How you accomplish this depends on how you are loading your JavaScript files. For example, let's say you are using `script` tags in your html file.  You can have `main.js` load after `secondary.js` like this:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="secondary.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help?

Comment: *Just make sure that secondary.js has executed prior to main.js. You can control that by the order of your script tags.* This line is the only thing relevant here

Comment: @LIam this helps because using `window` is one approach to sharing state between files. It's essentially sharing a global variable.

Comment: Also it's considered bad practice to pollute the global scope like this. Closures would make more sense

Comment: It's a reasonable approach. But I would elaborate to include local/session storage. & yes, technically not the best practice, but we're not all making masterpieces here. Sometimes it just needs to work.

Comment: `window.foo` is identical to `var foo`. `foo` is created in the global scope, which is `window`

Comment: @Liam it's nice to use `window` so we are explicit about putting things on the global scope. Is that a best practice? No. But, it's a start and is a basic solution to the OP's original question.

Comment: No it's not nice to use window. It's bad practice. Using closures is nice

Comment: @Liam, if the OP wants his code to be in separate files, how are closures going to help?

Comment: **OP:** *What I am trying to do is create a global function in `main.js` which can be utilized on the pages where `secondary.js` is loaded*.

Comment: Ok, Ignoring all talk about global scope, I go back to my initial point, **none of this is relevant**. This does not and will not help the OP. His issue was that he'd wrapped the [call in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417996/accessing-a-function-from-another-javascript-file#comment81790428_47417996) (ironically). So this is all just random bumf unrelated to the actual question being asked. *a main.js which **loads first** and then a secondary.js*