# Can ES6 imports be awaited?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, ecmascript-6

I saw [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47523068/859154) about differences between es6 imports vs require.
But one of the answers there caught my eyes:

> Thing is `import`() is actually async in nature.

Example :

```
const module = await import('./module.js');
```

[*mdn says nothing about it.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

I've been using imports for some time now but never knew that it can be awaited ??

I've also created an experiment (dummy angular test):

**1.ts**

```
export const a=3;
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; //no await here

@Component({
 ...
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor() {
    this.foo();
  }
  async foo() {
    const module =  await import('./1'); //<--- if I remove the await, it doesn't work
    alerqt(module.a)
  }
}
```

[image]

So it seems that import returns a promise ?

**Question**

What am I missing? I didn't have to await in the first two lines of where I imported Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; //no await

@Component({       
 ...
})
```

And where does it say that import returns a promise ?

[*Also , one of the webpack programmers : (or system.js) said :*](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader/issues/280#issuecomment-69491584)

> If import was just an asynchronous function, then it would no longer
>   be possible to statically analyze modules, as just like CommonJS
>   require, I could have import within arbitrary conditions etc.

[**But from my testing it does require await , which makes it asynchronisly evaluated.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdhds6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

So what is going on here?

Comment: Import has two sides: you can either use it in the beginning of a file (to import other components), or you can also use it in the code to load a javascript file dynamically (e.g. after the user changes the language of the application -> load the new language.json file). And this function is async, so you can resolve it using a promise. I don't really know where that's documented but already used that behaviour (for loading language files).

Comment: React loadable relies on import() async nature and it actually helps code splitting, as they well explain in the readme of the repo: https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable

Comment: @Larce Thank you. If i may ask  - what is the boundry where it is considered "beginig of the file" vs "not begining of the file" ? do you mean in a function ?

Comment: The way import works in module's, is different to how they work inside a function body.

Comment: It's a stage3 proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

Comment: Yeah exactly by "not the beginning of the file" I mean in any (function) body.

Comment: @Thomas Oh so it's a TS thing ? that's why it worked ?

Comment: I knew that this is a future JS thing. But TS seems to already support it.

Comment: It's not just a TS thing. Maybe you check [this](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports) out, about how JS imports/modules (will) work. And then there's the mentioned proposal for the [dynamic imports](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import). Atm you can't use them in plain JS in production, but they are coming, and eventually TS will simply get rid of the polyfills.