# React-native require any file

Tags: react-native, bundle, require

Can I use `require(...)` in React-Native to import any file, for example `file.txt` or a file with any other extension? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use require to import any kind of file. As per ES6 import/export is preferred over require. 
This link might help you understand it better : [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Edit:

Actually for using text file you have keep text in a .json file in object format. Simple text files cannot be imported.

For example text.json content:

```
   {
       'first_name': 'Vivek',
       'last_name': 'Verma'
   }
```

and then you can import it like

```
   import Text from 'path/to/text.json';
```

and use it like

```
   Text.first_name
   Text.last_name
```

Comment: I wonder how I would do it using import? What the syntax would be?

Comment: Right now I get 
`Unable to resolve module './labels.txt' from '...\index.android.js': could not resolve '...\labels.txt' as a file nor as a folder` while making a bundle