# Imports difference between ES5 and ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

How can you manage that in ES6?

```
    const withResponsiveness = require('../helpers/withResponsiveness.js').default;
    const ResponsiveLegend = withResponsiveness(Legend);
```

Comment: worth noting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `import`:

```
import withResponsiveness from '../helpers/withResponsiveness.js';

const ResponsiveLegend = withResponsiveness(Legend);
```

Comment: Not that easy. Also your way of exporting has to change.

Comment: @JonasW. It was already exported with `default` - that's enough for `import`.

Comment: @hsz just if you use Babel / Webpack / ... that transpiles one into the other.

Comment: @Toto If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it.