# Require Component vs import Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am starting to dive in JavaScript world. 
Which way is better to reuse JavaScript files/components.

```
let MainFooter = require('./partials/MainFooter.vue');
```

or

```
import MainFooter from './partials/MainFooter.vue'
```

Which is better to use and when?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: I think your question is more “require vs import”. Require inserts the required content at the line it is used, imports are sorted to the top of the file.