# getter inside module.exports and es6 style import (react navigator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

Can somebody explain how the module system in [react navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/react-navigation.js) works? There are getters inside module.exports (with node.js-like require()), and also es6 style export default in other files.
I completely stuck how to make sense of it. I tried to look into git history, but the initial git commit (first public release) already had this solution in place.

The [main file](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/react-navigation.js) (`src/react-navigation.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  get createKeyboardAwareNavigator() {
    return require('@react-navigation/native').createKeyboardAwareNavigator;
  },
};
```

[react-navigation-native/src/createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-native/blob/master/src/createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js):

```
export default (Navigator, navigatorConfig) =>
  class KeyboardAwareNavigator extends React.Component {
};
```

So why 
1. there is module.exports instead of export?
2. why there is a getter inside `module.exports`?
3. how can `require` and `export default` be mixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: 1. because CommonJS give ability require file in inner scope `for each` for example. 2. So the `get` always require current `().createKeyboardAwareNavigator` when is requested. 3. Because the `import` - es6 and `module.exports` - commonJS are features of nodeJS.