# Node.js require vs React.js import

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, require

I know that in Node.js, when you require some file with variables or functions, from the second time it is loaded from the memory. 
This concept is the same in import in React.js?
Can I load multiple variables or functions using import, and it will load from the memory the second time?

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Comment: Its good to know, but where is the answer for my question there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is UI library. It isn't related to `import` keyword. Any available JavaScript features can be used together with React, including `import` - or `require`, if it's available.

The question is about ES vs CommonJS modules. The former are universal, the latter are primarily used in Node but also suppored by Webpack and other bundlers, so both `import` and `require` can potentially be used in React application.

> Can i load multiply variables or functions using import, and it will load from the memory in the second time?

This describes caching behaviour that is specific to all JavaScript modules, including ESM `import`. A module is evaluated once, the export is cached and can be used on subsequent import.