# Nodejs import versus require

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Nodejs is the statement `import Obj from 'module_1'` the same as `const Obj = require('module_1')`? This is when Obj is supposed to be a Constructor. I want to know because using the import statement does not seem to work for me so I was wondering if there was an alternative way of writing it.

Comment: yes. node js uses common js module format and need to use require

Comment: As I understand it, the es6 import feature is available in NodeJS natively only through a special flag. More details in a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node/50641589#50641589). TLDR; Use experimental flag or a transpiler like Babel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Answer (score 1):

Import and require cannot both be used. You can either use require without installing/modifying anything or you can use imports only and adding
"type": "module", to your package.json file. They say you have to make your server.js file's extension as .mjs but .js works for me.
This is if you want to use both import and require:
https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/