# ES6 dynamic Import() vs AMD require()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs, amd

What is difference between:

- dynamic `import()` in the ES6+ technology and
- `require()` in the AMD technology (requireJS library)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: @connum disagree, there is a difference between `import()` and `import`.

Comment: Dynamic import is still a proposal, it's not part of ES6.

Comment: It is introduced on 21 November 2017 on the official V8 website. Also, can be found on MDN website officially. Yes, it is a standard.
https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

Answer (score 3):

There are some differences but `import()` can be considered as an official implementation of the legacy **AMD libraries** like `require.js`. Also, it brings a modern approach.

The self-evident feature of a legacy AMD is that it comes with the module definition besides import expression. This means you can define a module that can be imported asynchronously anywhere in the project.

If you don't have a transpiler like `BABEL` to polyfill EcmaScript proposals on your project or if you work on the legacy codebase and need an AMD solution for improving performance, considering to use some AMD libraries instead of dynamic import can be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few differences:

`require()` is synchronous, `import()` is asynchronous (returns a Promise).

`import` is a keyword defined in the ECMA spec, `require()` is just a function defined by some library.

You can use `require()` "natively" in NodeJS and not in browsers, and `import()` is specified for all JavaScript engines.

Now if you use a building pipeline (e.g. Webpack), they do actually do different things:

`require()` will bundle the required code into one bundle, just as `import stuff` would, whereas `import()` dynamically loads the module at runtime, just as `require.ensure` would ([doc](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/))

Comment: Given this question was specifically about AMD and requireJS, *both* `require()` and `import()` are asynchronous.

Comment: Especially mentioned about AMD which means the Asynchronous Module Definition not `commonjs require().`