# Why in JS React and Node handle importing differently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import

Why in JS,
React handles importing like this

```
import SomeThing from '../../components/SomeComponent/SomeThing';
```

while
Node handles importing like this

```
const someThing = require('../someWhere/someThing');
```

Is it purely a convention?
If so, are they exchangeable?
If not, why is it important to be done so?
Is there any difference between them behind the scene, e.g. performance?

Comment: This is solve your doubt https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/importing-a-component

Comment: `import` is ES6 and is not supported in node (*yet*) without additional workaround. [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks to your link, I starred two questions to study them. A link in a comment in your link provided detailed answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Answer (score -1):

`import` is ES6 that is "dumbed" down by babel to compile in all browsers
`require` is ES5. React is using import because behind the scenes it's using babel as compiler. They are not exchangeable, in the sense that in React you can use require and import, but in node natively you can just use require.

Comment: I think "dumbed" down is not a good phrase (`require` is neither smarter nor dumber than `import`), plus you can, with the right command line options, use `import` in node.

Comment: Well you can do everything with the right command, can't you? But this is an answer to a question not made. I interpret es6 => es5 as "dumbed" down, you may interpret the contents of " " as you wish.

Comment: `require()` is not related to the ES5 spec. `import` can also be used in NodeJS "natively", although still experimental