# ES Module alternative of popular packages

Tags: es6-modules

Is there a centralized repository where I can find ES module (ESM) alternatives for popular npm packages?

I'm looking for a mapping like:

```
'lodash' => 'lodash-es'
'react' => '@pika/react'
'react-dom' => '@pika/react-dom'
// etc
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367852

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jspm](https://jspm.org/docs/guide) instead of npm

jspm is a es module package manager

https://jspm.org/docs/guide