# VSCode insiders node debugger launches src files instead of the build

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

So I have this really neat project with some really neat debugging which has worked since forever but after a too long hiatus and now I can't seem to get it to work. Like I noticed this in the debug tab

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/inaba/Programming/Lewd/packages/main-site/src/index.js:1
import express from "express";
```

Here's my launch.json, which has worked for like [forever](https://github.com/inabahare/lewd2/blob/5907676e9e35711adf9bb59d576c664c624e5bcf/.vscode/launch.json)

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Main App",
  "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
  "program": "src/index.js",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outFiles": [
    "dist/**/*.js"
  ],
  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/../../.env",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--require=dotenv/config"
  ]
}
```

So what the heck? As far as I can tell I'm doing things right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that `--trace-warnings` in vscode debug, just add it into runtimeArgs.

don't forget to stop the debugging session if it is running

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Main App",
  "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
  "program": "src/index.js",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outFiles": [
    "dist/**/*.js"
  ],
  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/../../.env",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--require=dotenv/config",
    "--trace-warnings"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try require() instead of the import statement

Citing Node documentation here:

> import statements are permitted only in ES modules. For similar
> functionality in CommonJS, see import().

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements

Some detailed context here: [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)