# Still "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module" After adding "type":"module"

Tags: node.js

I know this is `require` / `import` ES6 thing. I have a project using `import` and files are all `.js`, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) all I need is adding `"type":"module"` into nearest **package.json**. This is my package.json at the same top level as server.js and env.js:

```
{
  "name": "my project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "many .js",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type":"module",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
"dependencies":{...},
"devDependencies":{...},
"scripts":{...},
"author":"John Doe"
}
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import cors from 'cors';
import env from './env';
```

Still got

> internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
> internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
> ^ Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'c:\project\env' imported from c:\project\server.js did
> you mean to import../env.js?

node is 14.9.0, using nvm.

launch.json

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have a simple approach, just change your module extension to .mjs, import it with .mjs extension, and then run with node --experimental-modules anything.js file

Comment: @JatinMehrotra there are tons of .js files to change.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27408#issuecomment-486613861 does this help?

Comment: Hi, if you still remember this question, [take a look of my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606033/5290519)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of Node.js, ["There is the ECMAScript module loader:", fifth point](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/packages.html#modules-loaders):

> It does no extension searching. A file extension must be provided when the specifier is a relative or absolute file URL.

So you will need to change one line:

```js
import express from 'express';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import cors from 'cors';
// import env from './env';
import env from './env.js';
```

as the error message already hint you:

```
[...] did you mean to import../env.js?
```

Comment: It's not, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Jeb50: What's the error message you got? I was answering based on your OP. If your error message changed please update your post.

Comment: it's about `import` and `require`. If you see my original post, the err msg is originated from there...

Answer (score 0):

If you do `"type":"module"`, then you can't import things like `import env from './env';`
You just need to do it as written below:

import env from './env.**js**';