# Why prefer es6 import over require?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I don't find good reasons to prefer es6 import over require in nodejs.
I read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) but it lists the difference between import/require that does not answer my question.

Right now:

- `import` has many issues for those modules that do not `exports.default` the features
- if an application support LTS versions, nodejs has limited support for `import` - like dynamic import (and/or it requires `esm` modules to work or tricky solutions)
- if the application doesn't need to work on browsers you are not forced to switch to es6-imports
- this feature will be marked as stable from October 2020 with nodejs 14

So, could you help me to understand:

- what are the right/sensible use cases to migrate an application codebase from commonjs?
- when migrating an application codebase from commonjs worth it? - I think when node10 will be at end-of-life

And also, as a module maintainer, is the benefit to migrating the codebase relative the in-browser execution only?