# Use import inside a nodejs usually using require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a NodeJS app with a lot of routes, functions, etc. I have a lot of files with `const xxx = require('yyy')`.
I now want to use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ldap-search
I thought my journey would be as peaceful as it has been for now, but I can't use it, let me explain: instead of the usual `require`, I have to use `import`, as described in the documentation:

```
import SimpleLDAP from 'simple-ldap-search';
```

I searched on StackOverflow, and I saw I could put `"type": "module"` in the top `package.json` file, but then if I do I can't use `require`... It seems unsolvable.

Does it mean I have to choose between using ES6 or CommonJS? I read this question: [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

1. I have the impression the `import` is more efficient, am I right?
2. Is it possible to use `simple-ldap-search` in my current node app without making big changes?
3. Is it possible to "convert" (I know it's not the precise term but I think you'll understand) the use of `require` to `import` and vice-versa?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As this [project issue](https://github.com/jxjj/simple-ldap-search/issues/15) states, it isn't possible to use require in a project that switched to `type: "module"` in its package.json. For these use cases one would need to use a loader like Babel, etc.

It is worth considering switching over to ES modules, i.e to add `type: "module"` to your top-level package.json. It is still possible to import a CommonJS module with `import` but it does not work the other way around.

Alternatively, you can switch back to a 2.x version of that package, from what I see they made the switch to ES modules from 3.0.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't use `import` in a commonjs file, you can use `import()`

This will make it more annoying when having to deal with the async loading, but is probably easier than converting your entire project to ESModules.

```
const simpleLDAPLoader = import('simple-ldap-search');
// later

async function () {
  const {default: SimpleLDAP} = await simpleLDAPLoader;

  const simpleLDAP = new SimpleLDAP();

}
```

Adn this will use the cached version every time you await the exisiting promise

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs

> Using require to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules have asynchronous execution. Instead, use import() to load an ES module from a CommonJS module.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, I have: `TypeError: SimpleLDAP is not a constructor`

Comment: I'l give it a try in runkit and see

Comment: Ahh because it's a default export, you need to get the `.default` from the module. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is going to help you in your case but I have found this solution for myself and I can use ES6 import and "require" at the same time.
In package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

And in your file:

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Works for my projects!