# How to import/export in JavaScript and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, export

I've seen 2 ways for importing modules in JavaScript and TypeScript respectively and I'm confused.

(1) Method 1: Import

```
const * = require('./runtime');
```

(1) Method 1: Export

```
exports.login = function() {};
```

(2) Method 2: Import

```
import * from './runtime';
```

(2) Method 2: Export

```
export function login() {};
```

May I know which one to use with in JavaScript and which one with TypeScript?

Comment: Both methods can be used in JavaScript and TypeScript. The first is called [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and the second [ES5 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct however the first 2 ones are older and used in jquery or lower versions of javascript and One of the major differences between require() and import() is that require() can be called from anywhere inside the program whereas import() cannot be called conditionally, it always runs at the beginning of the file.
you can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)