# import geofire-common with firestore for browser code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, vite

I'm a bit confused trying to use geofire-common in browser code.

In the beginning, I've made a successful attempt with NodeJS which uses `geofire-common` referenced [here in the Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) and which code looks like this:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module'; // <------ trick to get a require function
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = getFirestore();
const geofire = require('geofire-common'); //<---------- geofire-common
```

Then, I wanted to make this work from the browser side... and I stumbled upon[this example](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/1c4c6834f310bf53a98b3fa3c2e2191396cacd69/firestore/test.solution-geoqueries.js#L13-L29). In this example, I can see a 'require' function so I guess it has something to do with old school commonJS module:

```js
const geofire = require('geofire-common');
```

`Require` is not part of the standard JavaScript API and should be NodeJS specific (which is a bit strange because i thought the example was browser code), so I've tried to use an ES6 import..

```js
import {geofire} from 'geofire-common';
```

... without success :

```sh
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/geofire-common.js?v=738ba8db' does not provide an export named 'geofire'
```

If some of the JS experts around would be willing to shed some light about those 2 packages and help me to correctly import `geofire` if it's possible, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very interesting question, once I got into it, it was kind of confusing, since the imports used in JavaScript have changed, and there are a few differences depending on the use case.

First, we need to know where this Geofire module comes from; you mentioned the documentation and the example where we can see they use the command line to [install](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#install_helper_library) this library:

> ```
> // Install from NPM. If you prefer to use a static .js file visit
> // https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/releases and download
> // geofire-common.min.js from the latest version
> npm install --save geofire-common
> ```

As you can see, they are using NPM, which points to us that this is a [nodejs library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export). This is important because you were confused about the origin and if it was a commonjs module, which it seems to be. This also means it should be called using `require`, a function and also this cause not to work when using `import`, which can be used only for ES modules style, as quoted from the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require):

> ##### `require`
>
> The CommonJS module  `require`  always treats the files it references as CommonJS.
>
> Using  `require`  to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules have asynchronous execution. Instead, use  [`import()`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions)  to load an ES module from a CommonJS module.

Then you asked how to run this code on the browser side, which I think can be done using the HTML reference or downloading the js file as suggested in the [github repo](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js#html).

> Alternatively, you can include GeoFire in your HTML. To do so, download a minified or non-minified version of GeoFire from the [releases page of this GitHub repository](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/releases). Then, deploy it to Hosting in your Firebase project.
>
> ```js
> <!-- Firebase -->
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
>
> <!-- GeoFire (TODO: substitute in your own project id)-->
> <script src="https://my-firebase-project.web.app/geofire-5.0.1.min.js"></script>
> ```

I would also refer to the [API Reference](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#api-reference--geofire-for-javascript) for further guidance, I can see some differences on how to use the library between the firebase page and the API reference.

Finally, in the npm page we can see `geofire` as a dependent of `geofire-common`, and both have the same github repository, so I guess it has something more to do with the naming. I would say both are basically the same.

Comment: Makes sense. So I guess, I'll have to manage this dependency manually instead of using the npm package... Maybe https://browserify.org/ could help here, but I never tried it and the benefits may be limited vs using an HTML script tag.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use

```
import * as geofire from 'geofire-common';
```