# NodeJs + TypeScript + import/export cannot use import outside module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

How to make NodeJS with TypeScript and ES import/export to work together?

For the configs below, when I am trying to run app with import statements by `yarn start` I get an error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "ls",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Api",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node src/index.ts",
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "eslint": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
        "typescript": "^4.5.2"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions":{
        "target":"es2020",
        "module":"commonjs",
        "rootDir":"./src",
        "moduleResolution":"node",
        "esModuleInterop":true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
        "strict":true,
        "skipLibCheck":true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: @Sheppard25 how did you crack this issue? I am also in a similar situation, please help me.