# How do I replace ```require()``` in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord.js, require

I am following a [tutorial on Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#reading-command-files).  I have had to change `require` to `import` for `node:fs` and `node:path`.

On line 34, however:  (`const command = require(filePath);`) there is another require statement that's throwing the same error about E5.  My understanding from articles like [this](https://flexiple.com/javascript-require-vs-import/)  is `import` is always run at the beginning of the file.  So, how do I deal with this error?  `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`

I would also love to understand, why all the tutorials I see use `require`, but I always get an error and have to convert to `import`.

Here's my code:

```
import dotenv  from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
const token = process.env.DTOKEN;

// const fs = require('node:fs');
import fs from 'node:fs';


// https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-dirname-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
console.log(import.meta.url);

// const path = require('node:path');
import path from 'node:path';
// import path from 'path'
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);


// Require the necessary discord.js classes
import { Client, Collection, Intents } from "discord.js";
// const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);  // *** here's the line with the error ***
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});


client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Comment: `require()` is the older CommonJS import mechanism, while `import` is the newer ES6 module syntax. Node had modules before the language standardized.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you!  So, is there some systematic way for me to deal with this?

Comment: You can use a version of `import` that looks like a function call, `import("something")`, in an ES6 module (where everything is usually `import` and `export`), in Node. That doesn't work in browsers however (usually).

Comment: Replace each of these `require`s by `await import`. This works in `async` functions or on the top level.

Comment: @SebastianSimon your answer is what worked.  Doyou want to provide it as an answer?

Comment: @DBWeinstein Sorry, I’ve been really busy the last few weeks, but the `await import` approach is also mentioned in some of the answers here: [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31354559/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Making a variable receive an import you will have to deal with the Promises that will come, for me it was a bit of work, so I redid the importations with require, I also recommend it.

To write imports with require just go to your package.json or package-lock.json and enter

```
    "type": "commonjs",
```