# whats the difference between these two examples?

Tags: node.js, fastify

whats the difference between these two examples ? And which should you prefer to use ?

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';

const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: true
});

fastify.get('/', async () => {
  return { message: 'Hello' }
});

const main = async () => {
  await fastify.listen({port: 3000});
};
```

second

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger: true});

fastify.get('/', async (req, reply) => {
  reply.send({message: 'Hello'})
});

const main = async () => {
  await fastify.listen({port: 3000});
};
```

So in the first we use import and not reply.send

in the second I use require and reply.send

I watched two tutorials and thats why I am asking which should I use and what you prefer and whats the difference ?

Comment: The only difference is using ESM imports or Common JS require, that has been [answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31354559/1318694)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in comments, the main difference is [ESM vs CJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31354559/1318694) syntax, but as you spotted in the 1st example `reply.send()` is not used

As a general rule you can say:

- When there is an `async` handler, returning the response payload is the best choice.
- When there is no async handler, responding by using `reply.send()` is the best choice.

Because:

- if you have callback style processing, you need to use `reply.send()`
- if you can use `async/await`, returning is more readable

Because: if you write:

```
fastify.get('/', async (req, reply) => {
  reply.send({message: 'Hello'})
  return { farewell: 'bye' }
});
```

What do you expect as output? - `reply.send` will win because it is more "lower level" thing.

I explain it more deeply in my book about fastify (see my profile as I don't want to spam link here)