# D3 7.0.0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to import [d3](https://d3js.org/) into my node application but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ node src/main.js
this is logged from main.js 2021-07-20 2:33 PM
/Users/michaelosofsky/Developer/shh/node_modules/d3/src/index.js:1
export * from "d3-array";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelosofsky/Developer/shh/src/main.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried following the method of importing d3 described in [How to use D3 in Node.js properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948350/how-to-use-d3-in-node-js-properly):

1. `yarn add d3` (added 7.0.0 to my package.json)
2. Put `var d3 = require("d3");` in my main.js
3. Run `node src/main.js`

This seems to be exactly what's specified in answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949301/2848676.

How to I work around this error?

Comment: I got the same issue when upgrading to d3 7.0.0. Last working version is 6.7.0

Answer (score 3):

I found I could work around this issue by downgrading the version of d3 I was using:

1. `yarn remove d3`
2. `yarn add d3@4.12.2`
3. `node src/main.js`

Now it does not give me that error anymore.

I don't know the nuances of node module conventions well enough to explain it but I do see a change in d3 7.0.0 that pertains to modules, so maybe that had something to do with the root cause: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3501.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was on 7.0.1 and downgrading to 6.7.0 solved it

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i d3@6.*
```

works as well for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32714614)